# Grab data from multiple columns and sort by row in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to sort a google form response sheet with multiple duplicate responses into one set of responses, but still having it associated with the info in the first column. Here is a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X128gFJNnX8HohSapinnLpdMe5HNuE58Uby7rmMQJZ8/edit?usp=sharing) with the basics of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({A:C; A2:A, D2:E; A2:A, F2:G}, "where Col2 is not null order by Col1", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome thanks! If I wanted it to associate with two columns, how would I do that? Such as date and class?

Comment: explain your follow up question in more detail by sharing a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Updated the sheet

Comment: use: `=QUERY({A:D; A2:B, E2:F; A2:B, G2:H}, "where Col3 is not null order by Col1", 1)` your sheet updated